# sql developer export database -no object to export

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I created my database and add some tables, packages etc.
When I want to export my database tools->Database export... I have no object to export. I dont know where can be an issue.
I using oracle database 11g xe
[image]

[image]

[image]

I can see object and they all works

[image]

Comment: Does the "hotel" connection actually work and is able to see any object?

Comment: yea, I edited question to show - all works and are visible

Comment: I can't spot any problem. I'd try to export under some more priviledged account, like sys, if you have acces to it. But I don't think you need any kind of grant for this kind of export...but nothing better comes to my mind.

Comment: On the other hand - if granting "select any dictionary" to hotel user would solve the problem, there obviously is need for one.

Answer (score 4):

You use that screen to specify which objects you want to export, unless you want to export everything.

That screen is blank because you haven't asked it to show you anything yet.
[image]

Type something in the Name input area, and then hit the Lookup button.

If you just hit the lookup button, it will show you every object in your schema, and that could take a while.

[image]

I think it's easier to use the 'More' button and say show me what I have for Tables in Schema X.

[image]

Here I said, show me all the tables for my 'MOVEME' schema. I picked two of them, and move them over. That tells SQL Developer when you get to export the tables, just grab these two tables.

Since you also told it to export VIEWS on the previous screen, it will export EVERY SINGLE VIEW, unless you use this dialog to say, just export these 3 views please.

However, if you want to just export EVERYTHING of every type you checked previously, then you can skip this step and finish.

Comment: Thanks, it shows me where error can be, because on my default XE database it works, but when I created new database it doesnt work. For example when I type `select * from system.clients;` it shows me correct records, but on export manager when I select schema system and click lookup -it still blank - https://imgur.com/EuMrwTo

Comment: View - Log. Then click on the statements panel. You can see the queries we're running against DBA_OBJECTS or ALL_OBJECTS. Should help you debug what's going on in your database.